# How can I send clear or reset with Term::Cap?

Tags: perl, termcap, terminfo

When I output `tput clear | hexdump -c` I get different results if I'm on `kitty` or `xterm`. How can I use [`Term::Cap`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Term/Cap.html) to generate these terminal signals on the respective terminal?

What I've tried is a direct-copy-paste from the docs with setup,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::Cap;
use POSIX;
my $termios = new POSIX::Termios;
$termios->getattr;
my $ospeed = $termios->getospeed;

my $terminal = Tgetent Term::Cap { TERM => undef, OSPEED => $ospeed };
```

And then I thought this should work,

```
$terminal->Tputs('clear', 1, *STDOUT );
```

But alas, it does nothing.

If I provide a different non-existent name for the term (rather than `undef` which defaults to `$ENV{TERM}`, I get)

```
Can't find a valid termcap file at ./test.pl line 9.
```

So I know it's looking up the `termcap` file, and finding it.

Comment: termcap names are ***all*** 2-character names.  "clear" has 5.  termcap isn't terminfo.

Comment: @ThomasDickey thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Right way

All of termcap's signal names are two letters. For clear you'll want `cl`

```
$terminal->Tputs('cl', 1, *STDOUT );
```

You can find the full list on `man termcap`, which has a full list:

```
ch   Move cursor horizontally only to column %1
cl   Clear screen and cursor home
cm   Cursor move to row %1 and column %2 (on screen)
```

*Thanks to [Thomas Dickey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518274/thomas-dickey) for the answer in comments*

## Wrong way

Not sure what I was doing wrong, as a temporary work around I did

```
use constant CLEAR => do {
    open( my $fh, '-|', qw(tput clear) );
    scalar <$fh>;
};
```

This still has a spin up another process, but it worked fine. I won't accept this answer in the event anyone knows how to do this the right way.